# Vertical Scrolling + effects on top and bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am trying to make a design similar to this [Scroll Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxPHI.gif)

Any ideas on how to do this?

What I tried (failed): Vertical scrolling pageview where the middle child is a SingleChildScrollview. But the SingleChildScrollview stops the vertical pageview from working.

I tried adding a scroll controller to the Scrollview in the PageView, and animatedJumpToPage when I reached the bottom of the scrollview, but this has an ugly effect and theres gotta be a better way to do this

Answer (score 0):

Try using a ListView widget. It easily allows you to have a vertical scroll mechanism without adding any controllers or anything complicated.